# Image sequence training with CNN and RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm making my first steps learning Deep Learning. I am trying to do Activity Recognition from images sequences (frames) of videos. As a result i am facing a problem with the training procedure.

Firstly i need to determine the architecture of my images folders:

```
Making Food -> p1 -> rgb_frame1.png,rgb_frame2.png ... rgb_frame200.png
Making Food -> p2 -> rgb_frame1.png,rgb_frame2.png ... rgb_frame280.png
                      ...
                      ...
                      ...
Taking  Medicine -> p1 -> rgb_frame1.png,rgb_frame2.png...rgbframe500.png

                      etc..
```

So the problem is that each folder can have a **different number of frames** so I get confused both with the input shape of the model and the timesteps which I should use.
I am creating a model (as you see bellow) with time distirbuted CNN(pre trained VGG16) and LSTM that takes an input all the frames of all classes with the coresponding labels (in the above example  making food would be the coresponding label to p1_rgb_frame1 etc.) and the final shape of `x_train` is `(9000,200,200,3)` where `9000` coresponds to all frames from all classes, `200` is height & width and `3` the channel of images. I am reshaping this data to `(9000,1,200,200,3)` in order to be used as input to the model.
I am wondering and worried that I do not pass a proper timestep, as a result a wrong training , i have val_acc ~ 98% but when testing with different dataset is much lower. Can you suggest another way to do it more efficient?

```
  x = base_model.output
  x = Flatten()(x)
  features = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
  conv_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=features)    
  for layer in base_model.layers:
      layer.trainable = False
       
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(TimeDistributed(conv_model, input_shape=(None,200,200,3)))
  model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
  model.add(LSTM(16))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your model isn't obviously bad as far as I can see. As far as the different number of frames issue goes, the solution is to simply not do that. Preprocess your data to take the same number of frames from each action.

The deeper issue here is more likely just simple overfitting. You don't specify, but based off the fact that you are talking about hosting your training data on a single computer, I imagine that you don't have much training data, and your network is not learning the activities, but rather just learning to recognize your training data. Consider that VGG16 had about 1.2 million distinct training examples and was trained for weeks on top-end GPUs, just to distinguish 1000 classes of static images. Arguably, learning temporal aspects and activities should require a similar amount of training data. You had a good idea to start with VGG as a base and add onto it so your network doesn't have to relearn static image recognition features, but the conceptual leap from static images to dynamic videos that your network needs to learn is still a big one!

Comment: How can I get the same number of frames but in the same way having the most useful ones,if I do not take them and let them different will be a problem? About your second statement , indeed i don't have much training data , do you suggest to train them  into a classic 'Timedistirbuted Conv2d` layer instead of VGG?

Comment: You shouldn't depend on knowing which frames are most "useful". This is kind of what your neural network is supposed to learn. Just space the frames out enough, say by 50 or 100 ms. As for your second question, unfortunately, changing the network type won't get rid of the underlying issue. You need more training data, not a fancier network.